# Can't cast to ParameterizedType

Tags: java, generics, java-17

I am trying to get a Class<?> instance for the generic type. There is a lot of answers how to do that, but I am getting the error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Class cannot be cast to class java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType (java.lang.Class and java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

I use Java 17. The code to reproduce the error:

```java
class GenericTypeTest {
    @Test
    void showsTheError() {
        Generic<String> g = new Generic<>();
        assertEquals(String.class, g.getType());
    }

    static class Generic<T> {
        Class<?> getType() {
            Type type = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
            ParameterizedType paramType = (ParameterizedType) type;
            return (Class<?>) paramType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems from your question that you don't really understand what this code is for. This code can only obtain information that is hard-coded at compile-time (e.g. the hard-coded generic superclass of an anonymous class). This code can never get generic arguments for an instance, because such information does not exist.

Comment: Yep, It was. Thank you guys I have a little more understanding of this now. So the only one way to achieve my intention is to pass the class as a constructor argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The superclass of `Generic<T>` is `Object`, which isn't generic.

You need to subclass `Generic` for this to work:

```
Generic<String> g = new Generic<>() {};
```

Consider making `Generic` `abstract` in order to force it to be subclassed in order to instantiate it.

Comment: I see! But I don't need an abstract class at all. Is it possible to get Type of "this" class?

Comment: No. You need to do it like I've described (which is the same way that Guava type tokens work).

Comment: The error is pretty clear: `this.getClass()` is not an instance of `ParameterizedType`.  The `Type` hierarchy can be used to reflect over the generics of class and member _declarations_, but you cannot use it to determine the parameterization of an individual object, because that information is erased by the time you get to run time.

Comment: If you just want to get a particular `ParameterizedType` instance without creating subclasses, you can declare fields of the intended type and retrieve their declared type. But with the subclass approach you have an object whose compile-time type matches the `ParameterizedType` which is what solutions like Guava’s type token are about; they allow to create generic methods with type token parameter matching their generic signature with the runtime (reflection) operation. In theory, we could eliminate the overhead with a bytecode transformer after compilation, but it’s not worth the effort.